# error in loading image in picasso with varying height or width

Tags: android, picasso

This is my PhotosAdapter class for loading images with changing heigh or width.

```
import com.fivehundredpx.greedolayout.GreedoLayoutSizeCalculator.SizeCalculatorDelegate;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.Target;

 import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Julian Villella on 16-02-24.
 */

public class PhotosAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhotosAdapter.PhotoViewHolder> implements SizeCalculatorDelegate {


    private static final int IMAGE_COUNT = 500;

    // private final double[] mImageAspectRatios = new double[Constants.IMAGES.length];

    ArrayList<String> source_title = new ArrayList<String>();

    ArrayList<String> mImageResIds = new ArrayList<String>();


    private Context mContext;

//    @Override
//    public double aspectRatioForIndex(int index) {
//        // Precaution, have better handling for this in greedo-layout
//        if (index >= getItemCount()) return 1.0;
//        return mImageAspectRatios[getLoopedIndex(index)];
//    }

    @Override
    public double aspectRatioForIndex(int index) {
        // Precaution, have better handling for this in greedo-layout
        if (index >= getItemCount()) return 1.0;
        return mImageResIds.size();
    }


    public class PhotoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ImageView mImageView;

        public PhotoViewHolder(ImageView imageView) {
            super(imageView);
            mImageView = imageView;
            Log.d("PhotoViewHolderimage", imageView + "");

        }
    }

    public PhotosAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> source_title, ArrayList<String> source_filepath) {
        mContext = context;

        this.mImageResIds = source_filepath;
        this.source_title = source_title;

        Log.d("start", "start" + mImageResIds);

//        calculateImageAspectRatios();

    }

    @Override
    public PhotoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        ));

        Log.d("PhotoViewHoldermake", imageView + "");

        return new PhotoViewHolder(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PhotoViewHolder holder, int position) {

//        Picasso.with(mContext)
//                .load(mImageResIds.get(position))
//                .into(holder.mImageView);
        Log.d("onBindViewHolder", holder + "");

        Log.d("mImageResIds", mImageResIds.get(position));

        Picasso.with(mContext).load(mImageResIds.get(position)).into(new Target() {
            @Override
            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                int width = bitmap.getWidth();
                int height = bitmap.getHeight();
                holder.mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

                Log.d("Imageloadingfailed", " " + errorDrawable);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {


                Log.d("Imageloading", "placeHolderDrawable " + placeHolderDrawable);

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImageResIds.size();
    }

//    private void calculateImageAspectRatios() {
//        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
//        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
//
//        for (int i = 0; i < mImageResIds.size(); i++) {
//            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), mImageResIds.indexOf(i), options);
//            mImageAspectRatios[i] = options.outWidth / (double) options.outHeight;
//        }
//    }

    // Index gets wrapped around <code>Constants.IMAGES.length</code> so we can loop content.
//    private int getLoopedIndex(int index) {
//        return index % Constants.IMAGES.length; // wrap around
//    }
}
```

When this class run , data is there but not showing the image ,the onBindViewHolder method runs and there is an issue and due to this issue the picasso Override method onPrepareLoad and it shows the placeHolderDrawable null exception

i m using this code as reference https://github.com/500px/greedo-layout-for-android

If any one have any solution or any suggestion regarding this issue please help me out of this issue.
Sorry for my english and thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post the complete exception?

Comment: ok sir , i post my logcat error here...

Comment: 10-14 01:03:08.441 31714-31714/picmaster.com.mydemo D/ViewRootImpl: #3 mView = null
10-14 01:03:08.456 31714-31714/picmaster.com.mydemo V/ActivityThread: updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{6b053b8 token=android.os.BinderProxy@51d3221 {picmaster.com.mydemo/picmaster.com.mydemo.MainActivity}} show : true
10-14 01:03:08.466 31714-31714/picmaster.com.mydemo E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
10-14 01:03:08.466 31714-31714/picmaster.com.mydemo I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@51d3221 time:606160017

Comment: sir i think it not finds the imageView here in onBindViewHolder method...  or imageView length(height, weidth).

Comment: @Frederic Klein   sir the PhotoViewHolder holder is null , sir r u getting my issue?

Comment: Thats not the real exception. Could you please post the one with the NullPointerException + Stacktrace?

Comment: sir sorry if i m wrong but i new in android    this is my logcat when i run my project                                                                       
 picmaster.com.mydemo W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
 picmaster.com.mydemo I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
 /picmaster.com.mydemo I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
   picmaster.com.mydemo D/Imageloading: placeHolderDrawable null